# Java socket program hangs at sc.nextInt();

Tags: java, sockets

I am using the following code to learn about java socket programming. what it does is, client.java program get a number from the user and send it to the sever.java. Then the sever will multiply it by 2 and send it back to the client. In my client program, it successfully send the user input to the sever, but the sever hangs at the `number=sc.nextInt();` line waiting. But if I close the client.java program, it shows the the sever.java program did receive what the client sent and terminates the program with correct result.

**client.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int number, temp;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        Socket s = new Socket ("127.0.0.1",6666);
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (s.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Enter any number");
        number = sc.nextInt();

        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        p.print(number);//passing the number to the sever
        System.out.println("after passing the number");//Never reach here

        temp=sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println(temp);                   
    }    
}
```

Sever.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sever {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("sever starting");
        int number, temp;
        ServerSocket s1=new ServerSocket(6666);
        Socket ss=s1.accept();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
        number=sc.nextInt();  //Program waits here unless I close the client        
        System.out.println("this part never get executed: "+number);

        temp = number*2;//doesn't reach here till I close the client program
        System.out.println("Result temp: "+temp);
        PrintStream p=new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        p.print(temp);  
    }    
}
```

Comment: Flush the output by calling [`PrintStream#flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush()) after printing the data, or change the constructor arguments to auto-flush via [`PrintStream(InputStream, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean)).

Comment: @VinceEmigh Flushing is not enough, since server needs a whitespace (or end-of-data) to complete the `nextInt` call. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51353783/5221149).

Comment: Thank you all for providing comments and answers. Use of flush fixed the issue. thanks.

Comment: @Andreas Disregard that last comment. `Scanner` uses whitespace as a delimiter, so it makes sense, although haven't tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client is sending the entered number without any terminator, e.g. `42`. The `Scanner` on the server sees the `42` but doesn't know if that is the complete number, so it waits until connection is closed or a whitespace is received.

Easily fixed by using `println` on the client.

You may also need to `flush` the data, as [suggested by Vince Emigh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353727/java-socket-program-hangs-at-sc-nextint/51353783#comment89680139_51353727):

> Flush the output by calling `PrintStream#flush` after printing the data, or [change the constructor arguments to auto-flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean)).

You probably want to use `println` and `flush` on the server too, but since the server exits and hence closes the connection, the client will complete the `sc1.nextInt()` call regardless.